# Redirect url regex

Tags: regex, wordpress, regex-group, regular-language, regedit

I need to make some redirections in a wordpress site with "Redirections" plugin that allows only regex. Exactly i need to transform this url model:

```
http://example.com/cat1/subcat2/subcat3/subcat4/bar/this%20is%20page?start=130
```

To:

```
http://example.com/bar/this-is-page
```

Only if "bar" is in url. Anyway, last segment can be like this `/page`.

How can i obtain that result?

Comment: I've answered your question twice already -_- this will be the third time...

Comment: I closed last thread cause it was too generic :'D

Comment: Use [`(https?://[^/]*).*(/[^/]*/.*(?=\?)).*` replace with `$1$2`](https://regex101.com/r/aB5mPn/1) and then [`%20` replace with `-`](https://regex101.com/r/aB5mPn/2/)

Comment: @ctwheels Thats great! But "bar" must be in regex cause only in this case i allow redirect!

Comment: Change the second `[^/]*`  to `bar`